# What is the best way to check internet connection in background constantly?

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, realtek

I have a capability problem with the network card - internet disappears in some time whereas the wifi connection level doesn't change. Reconnecting to the same Wi-Fi spot solve this problem.

I want to write a workaround script that continuosly checks the internet connection (for example, one checking per 10 sec), and if it disappers, the script reconnect the Wi-Fi. I wanted to use `ping`, but its manual says it is unwise to use `ping` during automated scripts.

```
$ uname -a
Linux NS-COMP 4.11.0-13-generic #19~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 2 20:06:21 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [105b:e055]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2860
```

Comment: You can use the `speedtest-cli` program.  https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli

Comment: `host google.com>/dev/null || do something...`

Comment: Before writing the script , you can check if there some fix for your wifi module. please [edit here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/395377/edit) by adding the output of `uname -a` and `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: unload the kernel driver `sudo modprobe -rv rt2860` then load the `rt2800pci` : `sudo modprobe -v rt2800pci`

Comment: @GAD3R, rt2860 can't be unloaded: 'modprobe: FATAL: Module rt2860 not found.'. Yet rt2860 is always loaded. how's it possible?

Comment: And `sudo modprobe -rv rt2860sta`?

Comment: Yup, the same, the module wasn't founded.

Comment: Run `sudo modprobe -v rt2800pci` then check with `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` if the `Kernel driver in use: ?` is changed

Comment: when I had done this before, lspci said that rt2860 was in use. 
After that I removed rt3290sta drivers, add rt2860 to the blacklist and rt2800sta to /etc/modules. Now rt2800pci is in lspci.

Comment: Try to connect to your wifi , dose the problem persist ?

Comment: Connection is fine right now. The problem appears in some considerable time (e.g. 7-8 hours). 
It should be noted that I did the similar thing with rt2800pci before and it has the similar problem: symptoms are the same but WiFi connection stops to work till reboot.

Comment: The `rt2800pci` should be the right module , if the problem appear just reload the driver without rebooting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why the wifi keep disconnecting:**

According to the [debian documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/rt2800pci) you should use the `rt2800pci` instead of the `rt2860` currently loaded. witch solve your problem without executing a script to re-connect.

**a sample bash script**

If you need to run a bash script to connect when you loose your wifi connection (reloading the kernel module + reconnect) , this a sample bash script `reconnect`:

```
#!/bash/bash
if ! [ "$(ping -c1 8.8.8.8)" ]
then
    modprobe -r rt2860
    modprobe rt2800pci
    ip link set wlan0 down
    ip link set wlan0 up
fi
```

To run the `reconnect` script every 10 s:

```
while true ; do ./reconnect & sleep 10 ; done &
```

If the wifi drop after a few hours , it is better to create a cron job to run a script every 1 h : [some example here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/)